# how to extract twitts with special location and also special subject

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

please let me know if I am unclear,

I am extracting twits using Twitter API
my final goal is to extract twits in Chicago, also with the subject of pizza,

I mean finding all the twitts that are about pizza, and also the user location is in chicago,

I would have gotten two approaches:

**I tried the first approaach:**

1. applying geolocation in my search,

there is a problem with that, it seems it can't apply both the filters(chicago, pizza) with each other.

this is one screen shot of the result:[image: pic]

maybe because users don't say about their locations when they are twiting, so it can't be applied I am not sure.

**this is the code I am using:**

```
FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();
String keywords[] = {"pizza"};
    double lat = 41.793474;
    double lon = 87.984886;
    double lon1 = lon - .5;
    double lon2 = lon + .5;
    double lat1 = lat - .5;
    double lat2 = lat + .5;
double box[][] = {{lon1, lat1}, {lon2, lat2}};

fq.locations(box);
fq.track(keywords);

twitterStream.addListener(listener);
twitterStream.filter(fq);
```

**2**. the another approach and the better one is to extract the location of the user and use that for filtering.
I have no idea of how to apply this to my code.

**so I have two questions:**

1. what is wrong with the first approach I am using(do you think its because the user does not say about her or his location)?
2. if the first approach can't be applied for my case, how I can mix the second approach? I mean how I can extract the location of the user from their profile then apply that to the filter.

many thanks for taking the time :)

Answer (score 1):

When you stream and track both a word and a location, the two filters are OR'ed. You want them to be AND'ed. In other words, you will get results that match either filter. The best approach is to filter only for location. Then, write your own code that finds tweets in those results that match your word filter.

Another problem you will face is that very few users opt to include location information.